# Most efficient way to loop through and update rows in a large pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

This is my piece of code to update the rows of a dataframe:

```
def arrangeData(df):
hour_from_timestamp_list = []
date_from_timestamp_list = []
for row in df.itertuples():
    timestamp = row.timestamp
    hour_from_timestamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(
        int(timestamp) / 1000).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    date_from_timestamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(
        int(timestamp) / 1000).strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
    hour_from_timestamp_list.append(hour_from_timestamp)
    date_from_timestamp_list.append(date_from_timestamp)
df['Time'] = hour_from_timestamp_list
df['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.hour
df['ChatDate'] = date_from_timestamp_list
return df
```

Im trying to extract time, hour and chatdate from timestamp. The code is working fine. But when theres huge set of data, somewhere around 300,000 rows, the function is extremely slow. Can anyone suggest a better way to execute this function faster? 
For looping I have tried iterrows() which was even more slower. 
This is the document that im processing :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b9feadc32214d2b504ea6e1"),
"id" : 34176,
"timestamp" : NumberLong(1535019434998),
"platform" : "Email",
"sessionId" : LUUID("08a5caac-baa3-11e8-a508-106530216ef0"),
"intentStatus" : "NotHandled",
"botId" : "tony"
}
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: @jezrael editted the question with the data sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe here is possible use:

```
#thanks @Chris A for another solution
t = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')

t = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'].astype(int) / 1000)
#alternative
#t = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'].apply(int) / 1000)
#t = pd.to_datetime([int(x) / 1000 for x in df['timestamp']] )

df['Time'] = t.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df['Hour'] = t.dt.hour
df['ChatDate'] = t.dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: @jezrael, your code works fine, and its much faster than looping. One more thing tho, I'm getting the timestamps in GMT, how can I get it in my local time GMT +05:30? Is there a way to do that?